# Using photo_view package to fit image like BoxFit.cover

Tags: flutter, photoview

A basic usage as it, but in this case it is not fitted to screen borders. Is it possible to display it with a behaviour of BoxFit.cover ? A double tap make it fitted to the screen borders. Is it possible to display it this way initially?

```
PhotoView(
  imageProvider: NetworkImage(url),
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recently had the same problem here, but I found a solution. Although the answer is late by a couple months but here it is.

```
initialScale: PhotoViewComputedScale.covered,
```

Just add this line inside your `PhotoView`, it shows the same behaviour as `BoxFit.cover`.

Comment: `minScale` will overwrite `initialScale` value, so be sure it is not set.